# Apollo GraphQL basics Tutorial

Tags: javascript, nodejs, sqlite, sqlite3, graphql

Estoy probando el codigo del tutorial que ofrece Apollo graphql https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial. Actualmente me encuentro en el item de resolvers. Al correr la carpeta server me lanza un error que es necesario instalar sqlite3. He tratado de instalar sqlite3 con los comandos `npm i sqlite3@4.1.1` y `npm i sqlite3` sin ningún resultado exitoso. He revisado algunos post, como el siguiente post https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/587. Algunos usuarios recomiendan usar `npm rebuild` pero no me funciona. Alguien que me ayude?

```
$ npm start

fullstack-tutorial-server@1.0.0 start ...\ApollographQL-JV\fullstack-tutorial\start\server
nodemon src/index.js

[nodemon] 1.19.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node src/index.js`
D:...\ApollographQL-JV\fullstack-tutorial\start\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\connection-manager.js:31
        throw new Error('Please install sqlite3 package manually');
        ^

Error: Please install sqlite3 package manually
    at new ConnectionManager (D:...\ApollographQL-JV\fullstack-tutorial\start\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\connection-manager.js:31:15)
    at new SqliteDialect (D:...\ApollographQL-JV\fullstack-tutorial\start\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\index.js:14:30)
    at new Sequelize (D:...\ApollographQL-JV\fullstack-tutorial\start\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:242:20)
    at module.exports.createStore (D:...\ApollographQL-JV\fullstack-tutorial\start\server\src\utils.js:37:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:...\ApollographQL-JV\fullstack-tutorial\start\server\src\index.js:9:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Uff, no sé qué pone en esa imagen, la letra está borrosa y la veo demasiado pequeñita... ojalá hubiese otra manera de poner el texto en vez de como imagen... es una lástima que no exista otra manera de representar texto en una web excepto como imágenes. PD: Pon el texto como texto, no como imágenes por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución encontrada:

En las dependencias del archivo Package.json cambiar la siguiente linea:

```
{...
"sqlite3": "5.0.0"
...}
```

luego en git bash correr el comando `npm install` se instalara la dependencia de sqlite3.
Al correr `npm start` deja correr sin problemas el servidor graphql